# Is it possible to use the new hyper parameters feature of tensorboard 2.0 with models built with older versions of tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

Tensorflow 2.0 (in alpha now) contains a feature in tensorboard that allows managing different runs by the hyper parameters used in training.
https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/r2/hyperparameter_tuning_with_hparams

Is there a way to create compatible data files from older versions of tensorflow (1.12)?

Comment: As far as I know, you can't install separate tensorboard version for 2.0 API as of today. Therefore, you would need to maintain two separate versions, and be able to run them in parallel. So I don;t think it's feasible

Comment: @Sharky installing a separate tensorboard is simple (using virtual env), the problem is generating the data using the older API.

Comment: Installling is simple, but running is another stroy. You can't access `tensorboard.plugins.hparams` from old version. And I couldn't find separate tensorboard install package for 2.0 api